# MYSQL Update and add a value into cell

Tags: php, mysql

hello friends I want to update a cell in a table whit new content, but retaining the content that has. I need to add the new data separated whit comma or line break (is'nt relevant), preserving the data that have inside.

```
|id | title | referer|
|--------------------|
| 1 | post1 | google |
| 2 | post2 | yahoo  |
| 3 | post3 | bing   |
| 4 | post4 | google |
```

The table should look like this with new content added.

```
|id | title | referer           |
|-------------------------------|
| 1 | post1 | google,yahoo,bing |
| 2 | post2 | yahoo,bing,etc    |
| 3 | post3 | bing              |
| 4 | post4 | google,google     |
```

this is my code to insert new rows in my Database:

```
mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO posts (id,title,referer) VALUES (null,'$q','$referer')");
```

What would be the code to add information in the cell "referer" whit Comma separated or line break ?

thanks in advance

Comment: I would create a new table for the referrers. As you add each referrer, use the id of the title from the 1st table as the ID for the referrers. Then join both tables to get all referrers for post 1 and use explode to display them

Comment: How can you tell from your table schema (where `title` has duplicates) to which row you want to add a referrer?

Comment: @Brad can you give me a Link with more information about method that you suggest to me? thanks

Comment: Jose, You want to create 2 databases. One will have the posts in them(1,2,3,4) along with an referrers ID from table 2, and the 2nd will have a list of referrers.(google, yahoo etc) each with an ID that will go into the first table.. lets use post1. everytime you get a new referrer to post1, you would add a new line in the first table with the new referrer id. That way eventually you can add them up as in Google-20 referrers instead of displaying a line with many referrers. Read up on mysql table join, php explode, foreach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about what you might do with how separate them with commas unless you will want to create an array of variables and `concat` them into a single variable and use `mysql's CONCAT` function to update your table in order to keep your last field data:

```
$referes_list = '';
foreach ($referers as $referer) {
    $referes_list .= $referer . ", ";
} 
UPDATE referers SET referer=CONCAT(referer,'$referes_list') WHERE id='$id' ;
```

Comment: mysql_query('UPDATE posts SET referer = concat(referer,',',$refkey) WHERE id='$id'");     this code sends error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE

Comment: thanks, your new update says: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Well you are going to need to manage that by your self and see into what you have to put in the flaw! :)

Comment: mysql_query("UPDATE posts SET referer = CONCAT(referer,',','$refkey') WHERE id='$id'"); it works! thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to forgive me if my MySQL skills aren't the greatest, but what I would do here is simply get the current value, append a comma and new value to it, then update the cell.

...Or did I misinterpret your question?

Comment: yes, is what I need, but this comand not works for me
mysql_query("update posts set referer = referer + '$newref' where id ='$id'");

Answer (score 0):

In mysql there isnt "comma separated type", that is just a simple string or VARCHAR, so, you will need get previous data and concatenate it like string in php and then update it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like:

```
update t
    set referrer = (case when referer is null or referer = ''
                         then @newvalue
                         else concat(referer, ',', @newvalue)
                    end)
    where id = @id;
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_query('UPDATE tablename SET referer = concat(referer,", '.$value.'") where id="'.$id.'")';`
this should do it, it's untested though.